# for loop printing a value outside a loop and preserving the variable's value

Tags: php

hello all this is my code i am having problem in achiving this

```
 for($a=1;$a++,$a<25;){
echo $a.',';
 }
```

this gives something like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.......
but i dont want to print it i just want to store it into a variable say b and print it after the loop is over..

like

```
for($a=1;$a++,$a<25;){
$b=$a.',';
 }
echo $b;
```

can anyone just give me an idea how to do this ??
the variable should have the same value like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.............

Comment: First select a language: PHP or C++ or C ?

Comment: What does this have to do with C or C++?  The syntax in not valid for C or C++.

Comment: i think the logic would be similar

Comment: a pineapple is similar to a pinecone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is $b .= $a.",";

That will append each variable to $b. But you will also need to remove the last ',' either through a substring or a if statement inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

In the C++ language, you could use a vector:

```
std::vector<int> a;
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
  a.push_back[i];
}

// Access them outside the for loop:
std::cout << "a[5]: " << a[5] << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), and then [implode](http://www.php.net/explode) the resulting filled array.

```
$array = array();

for($a=1;$a<25;$a++){
    array_push($array, $a);
}

echo implode(',', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an [array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp) variable here. Store the values in an array and then run a`for` loop to print all the values.

Answer (score 0):

In `php` this is how you should do:

```
for($a=1;$a++,$a<25;){
    $b .= $a.',';
}
echo $b;
```

Also, I think your for is wrong. The normal form of a for should be `for(initialization ; conditions ; operations)`.

With your for you will achieve something like `2,3,4....`